# Information about $P'$ in $P \rtimes Q$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, p-groups, derived-subgroup

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. Suppose we have a group $G = P \rtimes Q,$ where $P$ is a non-abelian $p$-group and $Q$ is an abelian $q$-group such that it is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(P).$

Then we know that $P = C_P(Q)[P,Q].$

But from here I am unable to conclude anything about $P'?$ Any information or reference would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to conclude? If $Q=1$ then you just end up with $P=C_P(1)$, from which you should expect no more information.

Comment: Can we say anything about $P^{'} \cap C_P(Q)$ or $P^{'} \cap [P,Q]$?

Comment: I can tell you that $Q$ is faithful on $P/P'$ (in fact on $P/\Phi(P)$, where $\Phi(P)$ is the Frattini subgroup). I think that's all you can hope for in complete generality, but maybe someone knows more.